# Getting an error in a Do Loop

Tags: vbscript

This is a small bit of code which has the error I am having.
The SQL Statement at the begginning is this

```
sqlStr = "SELECT Computer, Room_Num, Speed, Num_CPUs, OS_Type, HDD_Size 
FROM Computers WHERE Num_CPUs = 1 OR Speed < 2.1 OR HDD_Size < 300 ORDER BY Room_Num" 


Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    recordsStr = recordsStr & objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Computer").Value & _ 
    vbTab & pad(objRecordSet.Fields.Item("HostName").Value,12) & _
    vbTab & pad(objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Room_Num").Value,14) & _
    vbTab & objRecordSet.Fields.Item("CPU_Type").Value & _
    vbTab & objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Speed").Value & _
    vbTab & objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Num_CPUs").Value & _
    vbTab & objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Bit_Size").Value & _
    vbTab & pad(objRecordSet.Fields.Item("OS_Type").Value,12) & _ 
    vbTab & objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Memory").Value & _
    vbTab & objRecordSet.Fields.Item("HDD_Size").Value & vbCrLf 
objRecordSet.MoveNext
```

Having the error on the second line:

```
recordsStr = recordsStr & objRecordSet.Fields.Item("Computer").Value & _
```

The error is:

> Item Cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

Ok somehow i fixed that error, now getting a new one on a line of code that i did not even touch...

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open dataSource
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRecordSet.Open sqlStr , objConnection
objRecordSet.MoveFirst
```

Getting an error in the line

```
objRecordSet.Open sqlStr , objConnection
```

Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: That means that one of your fields doesn't exist. `Computer, Hostname, Room_Num, Cpu_Type, Speed, Numb_CPUs, Bit_Size, OS_Type, Memory, HDD_Size` One of those is not in your query, or is mispelled or something.

Comment: Also, your second line is actually all of the lines in your `DO` loop. That's one big line that spans multiple lines with that `_` at the end. So it could be any one of those items that is missing/mispelled/fat-fingered. Check your SQL statement and make sure it matches. You can add your SQL statement here in the Question and perhaps we can help figure out where the mismatch is.

Comment: You need to provide more context than just one statement before the loop. Use the [edit] link to update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query:

```
sqlStr = "SELECT Computer, Room_Num, Speed, Num_CPUs, OS_Type, HDD_Size 
FROM Computers WHERE Num_CPUs = 1 OR Speed < 2.1 OR HDD_Size < 300 ORDER BY Room_Num"
```

You bring through the following fields, `computer, room_num, speed, num_cpus, os_type, and hdd_size` But... in your Do loop you try to get `Computer, Hostname, Room_Num, Cpu_Type, Speed, Num_CPUs, Bit_Size, OS_Type, Memory, HDD_Size`

Notice here that `Hostname, bit_size, and memory` are not present in your query. You can't request those from your recordset because they aren't in your recordset because they are not in your query. Try:

```
sqlStr = "SELECT Computer, Room_Num, Speed, Num_CPUs, OS_Type, HDD_Size, Hostname, Bit_size, memory 
FROM Computers WHERE Num_CPUs = 1 OR Speed < 2.1 OR HDD_Size < 300 ORDER BY Room_Num"
```

And assuming those are available in your `computers` table, it will start working.

Answer (score -1):

This is to show that your error message (typically) is caused by missing/misspelled field names:

```
>> Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
>> cn.Open "DSN=AdvWork"
>> Set r = cn.Execute("SELECT TOP 1 AddressID FROM Person.Address")
>> WScript.Echo r("AddressID").Value
>> WScript.Echo r("AdressID").Value
>>
33
Error Number:       3265
Error Description:  Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
```

The first 'missing link' is "HostName"; if you look carefully, you'll find more.

Comment: Some how that error got fixed but now have a new one in     Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open dataSource
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRecordSet.Open sqlStr , objConnection
objRecordSet.MoveFirst

Comment: in the format seperating the code it is up in the first post.

Comment: If you have a question that has nothing to do with a Do loop, ask a new one.